# What does creating a simple docker parent image actually do?

Tags: docker, docker-image

I'm following the instructions on Docker's website on [building a parent image](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages/#create-a-full-image-using-tar).  I'm very new to Docker.  I'm on a CentOS 7.5.

1. I ran the [mkimage-yum.sh](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/mkimage-yum.sh) script suggested on the Docker website for CentOS. I didn't understand why the last line of the script, `rm -rf "$target"` was there because it seems to delete all the work done by the script. So I commented it out and it leaves a directory `/tmp/mkimage-yum.sh.ahE8xx`, which looks like a minimal linux image with the typical linux file structure (e.g. `/usr/`,`/etc/`)
2. In my home directory, I compiled the program,

`main.c` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    printf("Hello Docker World!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Using `gcc -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -o hello main.c`, I compiled the code to a statically linked executable as prescribed in the docker webpage.

3. I created the `Dockerfile`,

e.g.

```
FROM scratch
ADD hello /
CMD ["/hello"]
```

4. I start up the `dockerd` server and in a separate terminal I run `docker build --tag hello .`

The output is :

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 864.8 kB
Step 1/3 : FROM scratch
 --->
Step 2/3 : ADD hello /
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a38d49d40e50
Step 3/3 : CMD /hello
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3bcbb04c367f
Successfully built 3bcbb04c367f
```

Gee whiz, it looks like it worked! However, I still only see `Dockerfile  hello  main.c` in the directory I did this. Docker clearly thinks it did something, but what? It didn't create any new files.

5. Now I run `docker run --rm hello` and it outputs `Hello Docker World!`.

However, I get disconcerting errors from the `dockerd` server:

```
ERRO[502548] containerd: deleting container                error=exit status 1: "container f336b3a5505879453b4f7a00c06acf274d0a5f8b3d260762273a2d7c0a846141 does not exist\none or more of the container deletions failed\n"
WARN[502548] f336b3a5505879453b4f7a00c06acf274d0a5f8b3d260762273a2d7c0a846141 cleanup: failed to unmount secrets: invalid argument
```

**QUESTIONS** :

1. What exactly did `docker build --tag hello .` do?  I see no output from this.
2. What are the `dockerd` errors all about?  Maybe looking for the docker image not created by `docker build`?
3. How does the `mkimage-yum.sh` fit into this?  Why does it delete all the work that it does at the end.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `--rm` with `docker run`, the container will run then delete itself.  If you want to keep the container, remove the `--rm` from the command.
The command `docker build` will grab the dockerfile and create a local image, in you case, from scratch with the image name of `hello`.

Comment: And where should this image be?  If I just run `docker build --tag hello .` and then `docker run hello`, I still cannot find the image.

Comment: are you able to see an image when you run "docker image -a" (w/o double quotes)?

Comment: So the image resides in the operating system you are currently using.  Like PC84 said, `docker image -a` or `docker images` will show them to you.  They are not physical images, or files that you can take with you.  The dockerfile is the blueprint and the image is the result of that blueprint in your computer.  That image can be pushed to a repository, but that's a topic for another day.

Comment: Ok, when I run `docker run --rm hello` and then inspect `docker images`, it is still there.  I can still go on to run `docker run hello` and it happily executes the program.  This doesn't seem to make sense with your answer.  Also from the `docker run` manpage "--rm=true|false ... Automatically remove the container when it exits. The default is false."  It seems that `--rm` is by default false which (I think) would make it superfluous.

Comment: I apologize but I don't understand what you are trying to tell me.  I think it is best if you go to the Docker support or documentations page, or maybe take a Docker class in Udemy, Youtube, etc.  Sorry couldn't help you.

Answer (score 0):

You will not see any additional files created in your folder. To see the created image, run command `docker images`. Here you should be able to see your image built with tag `hello`.

When you run `docker run <imagename>` it starts up a container with the provided image. That's why you see your C program's output